# Why iptables rule setup in initContainer `istio-init` works in application container?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am reading the doc of [istio](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2019/data-plane-setup/). It says:

> istio-init This init container is used to setup the iptables rules so that inbound/outbound traffic will go through the sidecar proxy.

In my understanding, initContainer and application container are separated except that they share same network namespace. So why would iptables setup in initContainer still persist in application container?

Comment: Does the pod run with `hostNetwork: true`?

Comment: @zerkms I didn't actually installed istio, accroding to it's document, this should not be required.

Comment: Have you seen [Understanding IPTables snapshot](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Understanding-IPTables-snapshot#iptables-schematic)? I think that should answer your question.

Comment: @Jakub Wow, that's exactly what I need. I didn't think of the possibility of docker using host kernel because the existance of windows image.

Comment: @NickAllen More than happy to help. I've posted that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, Iptables rules are briefly described [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Understanding-IPTables-snapshot).

There is also a Iptables Schematic:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A single network namespace shares a (virtual) network adapter between all the process namespaces (which means the other containers the pod will start). This is where changes are persisted.

Iptables configures rules that are set in a network namespace configure that shared adapter, so changes to networking in an init container persist when the application containers and sidecars start later in the same network namespace, and use the same adapter.

Comment: So where did iptables save all those rules and in what form? Can we saw those rule if we run `iptables -L` in application container?