# Whitelisting istio required ports

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Given that

- i have 1 master and 2 worker nodes
- istio related pods (istio-cni, istiod, istio-proxy, istio-operator, prometheus, kiali) are schedulable only on my worker nodes..

How do I apply https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/requirements/#ports-used-by-istio in terms of iptables?

How do my firewall rules differ from pod-internal only?

my plan is to execute something like in all of my worker nodes

`sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" port protocol="tcp" port="15000" accept' && sudo firewall-cmd --reload`

Is this okay? My knowledge is not that deep in firewalls

Comment: Hi @letthefireflieslive, I would start by checking the requirements for a specific platform.
Here is [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/) to starting istio on various platforms. For example on GKE and private clusters is mandatory to open port 15017. Is port 15000 a specific port you want to open or just an example? I would not recommend opening ports outside of the wall other than required. 

Ports used by istio shouldn't be used inside your application.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67223438/why-iptables-rule-setup-in-initcontainer-istio-init-works-in-application-conta/67264056#67264056) is also similar topic. If you are intersted about iptables inside istion-proxy-injected  pod, you can read [this doc](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Understanding-IPTables-snapshot#iptables-schematic).